# Catching exception in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT project, in which I have a method like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
    {
        if (caught.getClass()== MyException.class)
        {
            //do specific stuff
        }
        else
        {
            // do generic stuf
        }
    }
```

Where `MyException` is a custom defined exception. A colleague of mine told me, that since this will get converted into JavaScript, where "there are no classes", this is not a very good idea and I should use:

```
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
    {
       try {
         throw caught;
       } catch (MyException e) {
         //do specific stuff
       } catch (Throwable t) {
         //do generic stuff
       } 
    }
```

Since the first way actually works (at least on my side), will there be any problem if I continue to use it, or should I go with the second way?

Comment: There is no problem in your code. You can go with it. Just keep the custom exception class in shared folder so that it can be accessed both at client and server side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `instanceof` operator, it works -

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
{
    if (caught instanceof MyException)
    {
        //do specific stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // do generic stuf
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personnally prefer the second way.

Any Exception you do not catch, can be handle by a global UncaughtExceptionHandler.

```
GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
  public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
    // TODO Global Exception Handling ...
  }
});
```